# How to mask a div when it's in front of another div

Tags: html, css, z-index, display, clip

I want a div to be a fixed part of the background of another moving div. 
So imagine the top half of the website is a white div. The bottom half is a blue div with red circles floating around on it. 
When the user scrolls, the blue div will scroll up on top of the white div. The red circles have a position=fixed and are randomly positioned on the page. I want them to only show up on the blue div, so the white div has to hide them.

I tried doing this with z-indices but I can't get all the overlaps to work at once. 
Basically, the red circles need to simultaneously be behind the white div and in front of the blue div, but the blue div has to be in front of the white div too. 
I looked into clips but I've only figured out how to clip the red circles in a position relative to themselves. Not to clip out an area of the screen so that when they move into that area they mask out. Also not sure how to have the clip move with the white div out of the page when the user scrolls.

[image]

Comment: *the red circles need to simultaneously be behind the white div and in front of the blue div, but the blue div has to be in front of the white div too* --> mathematically this is impossible: if A > B and C < B you cannot have C > A

Comment: yes but I'm hoping there's some css trick to get around it. for example applying a mask on the element based on another div. just not sure if that's possible

Comment: share your code, probably this is easier than you described it

Comment: Maybe share a picture that explains what you mean

Comment: Added a picture

Comment: Is there anything in the white div or is it just white?

Comment: there are some child divs inside it

Comment: And you want those child to be fixed or can they scroll up?

Comment: The children of the white div should scroll up with it. It’s only the red circles that are fixed

Comment: good, that's doable. If they had to be fixed it would have required some JS

Answer (score 0):

If the red circles are simply red circles you can consider a trick with `background-attachment:fixed`

```css
.top{
 background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/600) center/cover;
 height:200px;
}
.bottom{
 /* Random circles*/
 background-image:
  radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 95%,transparent 100%),
  radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 95%,transparent 100%),
  radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 95%,transparent 100%),
  radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 95%,transparent 100%),
  radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 95%,transparent 100%);
 background-position:
  10px 10px,
  10px 150px,
  200px 10px,
  200px 300px,
  300px 80px;
 background-size:40px 40px;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
 height:400px;
 margin-top:-50px; /* To create a small overalp with top*/
}
```

```html
<div class="top">

</div>
<div class="bottom">

</div>
```

Comment: they're actually divs with a 50% border-radius and a blur filter. I'm appending them with javascript with random settings and animate their position, scale, and opacity with transform. Imagine transparent bubbles slowly moving across the screen. Can I still use this trick with those?

Answer (score 0):

Since the blue div scroll with the white, you can have the blue div position be absolute. Being under the whte div, it will still scroll. With two posiion elements you can make the z-indexes work by having your blue div's z-index be -2 and the red circles' z-index be -1.

```css
html, body, .container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.top, .bottom{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.top{
  background: white;
  .content{
    margin: 5%;
    color: red;
  }
}
.bg{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: -2;
  .content{
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
.circle{
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.c-1{
  left : 25%;
  top : 25%;
}

.c-2{
  left : 60%;
  top : 40%;
}

.c-3{
  left : 10%;
  top : 78%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>some text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="circle c-1"></div>
    <div class="circle c-2"></div>
    <div class="circle c-3"></div>
    <div class="bg">
     <div class="content">
       <p> some text </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```